# Line Breaker Application

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm designing an application where I'm supposed to take a line of strings and a break number. I'm quite new to this so I'm confused about the logic of how to loop and 'break' the string. I'm also encountering a runtime error in my runner class "String index out of range: 0(in java.lang.String)" as it highlights the last line of my code (the while perimeter) .

Example of an input would be:

h e l l o w o r l d

3

Example of an output would be

hel

low

wor

ld

My code so far is

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineBreaker
{
   private String line;
   private int breaker;

   public LineBreaker()
   {
    this("",0);
   }

   public LineBreaker(String s, int b)
   {
       s = "";
       b = 0;
   }

    public void setLineBreaker(String s, int b)
    {
        line = s;
        breaker = b;
    }

    public String getLineBreaker(String s, int b)
    {
        String box = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            if(i == s.charAt(b))
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        return box;
    }
}
```

And my runner class:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineBreakerRunner
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       String choice = "";
       do{
           System.out.println("Enter a group of characters please.");
           String characters = keyboard.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Enter an integer please.");
           int number = keyboard.nextInt();
           LineBreaker test = new LineBreaker();
           test.getLineBreaker(characters,number);
           System.out.println("Do you want to enter more data?(Y/N)");
           choice = keyboard.nextLine();
       }while(choice.charAt(0) == 'Y'||choice.charAt(0) == 'y');
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks for your time!

Comment: Use `substring` in the `String` class as well as a `for` loop. Also, where are the variables `s` and `b` in your class? It looks like you don't quite understand constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your if-statement `if(i == s.charAt(b))`
Doing so will only do a printing when the ASCII value of the current letter equals to the index.

## Printing Directly

If you wanted to print directly from the method, your complete method will look like:

```
public void getLineBreaker(String s, int b)
{
    for(int x=0; x<s.length(); x++){
        System.out.print(s.charAt(x));
        if((x+1)%b == 0)               //print a newline every n characters (where n is b)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

## Returning the String

If you only want to create a String and return it in the end, you can do it like this:

```
public String getLineBreaker(String s, int b)
{
    String str = "";
    for(int x=0; x<s.length(); x++){
        str += s.charAt(x);
        if((x+1)%b == 0)    
                str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

## Building string with StringBuilder

And for better performance, you can also use a StringBuilder:

```
public static String getLineBreaker(String s, int b)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int x=0; x<s.length(); x++){
        str.append(s.charAt(x));
        if((x+1)%b == 0)    
                str.append("\n");
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

---

**Tested Output:**

```
hel
loW
orl
d
```